# Html2Canvas not rendering image properly

Tags: javascript, php, html2canvas

Here is my code, and i am not getting proper Image, specially in Crome.

```
function capture(){
    html2canvas(document.querySelector(".pc_table"), {
      logging: true, 
      letterRendering: 1, 
      allowTaint: true,
      useCORS: true 
    }).then(canvas => {
      console.log(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.9));
    })
}
```

Sometimes Image render Properly (URL: https://www.gadgetlnn.com.bd/index.php?route=product/pcbuilder) click on capture, but mostly Image is like
[image: IMG]
I tried a lot of things like:
https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/722
but nothing works fine. Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is because of the broken images.
I simply make to load images correctly. And it worked out.